# Warning: Missing argument 2 for l()

Tags: 7

I try to show image that have link but i received error like this is anyone know and can help me .. thanks

Here's my code

```
<div id="profil">
'.tabel_budgetcenter().'    
</div>
<div id="pengeluaran_pp">
'.tabel_pengeluaranpp().'   
</div>
<div id="cuti">
'.l(theme('image', array(
    'path' => 'misc/images/print_24.png',
    'alt' => 'to pdf',
    'title' => 'to pdf'), "print/lpr_budget/coa_all_pdf/".$thn."/".$coacode, array("attributes"=>array('target'=>'_blank'),'html'=>TRUE))).'
'.l(theme('image', array(
    'path' => 'misc/images/excel.png',
    'alt' => 'to excel',
    'title' => 'to excel'), "print/lpr_budget/coa_all_xls/".$thn."/".$coacode, array("attributes"=>array('target'=>'_blank'),'html'=>TRUE))).'

'.tabel_budgetcenter2().'
</div>

</div>';
return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
theme('image', array(
  'path' => 'misc/images/print_24.png',
  'alt' => 'to pdf',
  'title' => 'to pdf')
```

Should be this:

```
theme('image', array(
  'path' => 'misc/images/print_24.png',
  'alt' => 'to pdf',
  'title' => 'to pdf'))
```

You missed the closing parenthesis in both this, and the next link as well.

So that means you need to change this:

```
l(theme('image', array(
  'path' => 'misc/images/print_24.png',
  'alt' => 'to pdf',
  'title' => 'to pdf'), "print/lpr_budget/coa_all_pdf/".$thn."/".$coacode, array("attributes"=>array('target'=>'_blank'),'html'=>TRUE)))
```

To this:

```
l(theme('image', array(
  'path' => 'misc/images/print_24.png',
  'alt' => 'to pdf',
  'title' => 'to pdf')), "print/lpr_budget/coa_all_pdf/".$thn."/".$coacode, array("attributes"=>array('target'=>'_blank'),'html'=>TRUE))
```

In order to correct the misplaced closing parenthesis that you put at the end of l(), instead of at the end of theme().